# What theme/styling is used in the Plotly Dash Documentation? Or: how to create a thoroughly "dark" Dash App

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Plotly's Dash has a very nice dark themed [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com), whose styling however does not seem readily available to the user (the default Dash app is unstyled). I would like to create a dark themed Dash app whose components look pretty much like the Dash documentation. The closest easy solution I have come across is to use a dark theme from the the [Dash Bootstrap Components Themes](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/themes/) i.e.

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG])
```

together with the `"plotly_dark"` [template](https://plotly.com/python/templates/) for graphs. However, this does not work for all components, in particular the [`dcc.Tabs()`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tabs) or [`dcc.RangeSlider()`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/rangeslider) elements in my app are still of a different (light) style. The way they look in the dash documentation would be perfect for my app.

So the question is: is there an easy way to create a thoroughly dark themed app, where all core components are consistently styled? And further: is it possible to apply the same style as in the Dash [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com)?

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation on using [Dash DAQ](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-daq/darkthemeprovider) for implementing dark mode, you can check it out here which includes the API reference and examples.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but does not seem to be a straightforward solution e.g. my app is organized into rows and columns using Dash Bootstrap Components and otherwise uses Dash Core Components. Simply using 
```import dash_daq as daq

theme = {
    'dark': True,
    'detail': '#007439',
    'primary': '#00EA64',
    'secondary': '#6E6E6E',
}

app.layout = daq.DarkThemeProvider(theme = theme, 
    children = dbc.Container([...])
)
```
does not work.